# Update table with average

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem with my query:

```
UPDATE [DIM_Category]
SET Category 3 = (SELECT AVG(Category 2)
FROM [DIM_Category] GROUP BY Category)
```

I want to do like in this exemple and I don't know how.

| Category | Category 2 | Category 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| OCS | 10800 | 20350 |
| OCS | 29600 | 20350 |
| Netflix | 24000 | 23000 |
| Netflix | 22000 | 23000 |

Comment: Don't do that to yourself. You are creating yourself a nightmare. It is not properly normalized because you are storing calculated values for a group across rows. If you need this data frequently I would suggest creating a view instead of mangling your table.

Comment: @SeanLange it's for a procedure that I will start 1 time per month ! 
It is not possible to do like how I started ? 
Just select execute the select without the update is easy but with it, I don't know how to do it ?

Comment: It doesn't matter how often you need to view or update this information. What you are trying to do with this goes against the concept of a relational database. Yes you could kludge a query to do this but it is just awful.

Comment: As Sean has said, there really isn't any justification for storing this. As an aside it seems highly unusual to be storing metrics like this in a table that is presumably a dimension (based on the prefix) this is another code smell. Your query is possible, but a to do this calculation will be a much more robust solution. [Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ODPhYd9W)

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your comment ! 
I will try to do it in an another way next time :)
They forced me to do like this :c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as I dislike the concept you are doing here the query itself needs to be correlated. One way you can do that easily is with a cte. This will work on the example you posted. I included my code to create a table so I had something work with. You would obviously not need that part. ;)

```
create table DIM_Category
(
    Category varchar(20)
    , Category2 int
    , Category3 int
);

insert DIM_Category
(
    Category
    , Category2
) values
    ('OCS', 10800)
    ,('OCS', 29600)
    ,('Netflix', 24000)
    ,('Netflix', 22000);

with CatAvg as
(
    select Category
        , CatAverage = AVG(Category2)
    from DIM_Category
    group by Category
)
update c
set Category3 = ca.CatAverage
from DIM_Category c
join CatAvg ca on ca.Category = c.Category;

select *
from DIM_Category;
```